# Is there a performance difference in MySQL between IN and several OR clauses?

Tags: mysql, performance

Is there any performance difference between the two following queries:

```
SELECT foo,bar FROM table WHERE id IN (1,2,3);
```

and

```
SELECT foo,bar FROM table WHERE id = 1 OR id = 2 OR id = 3;
```

I'm sure the difference in negligible in a small example like this, but what about when the number of valid IDs is much larger?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782915/mysql-or-vs-in-performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimizer is more likely to be able to optimize `WHERE id IN (1,2,3)` than `id = 1 OR id = 2 OR id = 3`. I also think that using `IN` is more readable here.

Use `WHERE id IN (1,2,3)`.

Answer (score 0):

This was an assignment in a comp.sci database class I took, back in the dark ages. Turns out there's not too much of a performance difference between the two within measurement limits, but the `... IN (...)` version does result in a much smaller query due to less characters required to construct it.