# Select Syntax - is "something = ('this' or 'that' or 'other')" ok to do?

Tags: mysql, select, syntax

I am using MySQL v5.5.27. I usually would write this SELECT statement like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM table 
WHERE something = 'this' 
    OR something = 'that' 
    OR something = 'other' 
    AND thingamajig = 'one' 
    OR thingamajig = 'two'
```

But would this SELECT statement provide the exact same result?

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM table 
WHERE something = ('this' OR 'that' OR 'other') 
    AND thingamajig = ('one' OR 'two')
```

I have tried running this and it *seems* to be working. Just want to make sure this second way of doing things won't return errant data in some way that I can't think of.

Thanks for any insight, assistance!

Comment: Withou parens, your first query is probably wrong due to the order of precedence for AND and OR operations.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend to use parentheses to clearly group the order of your search criteria.

Your 2nd `SELECT` statement is much more clear than your first.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM table 
WHERE something = ('this' OR 'that' OR 'other') 
AND thingamajig = ('one' OR 'two')
```

Remember, you can also use the `IN` operator when you have multiple values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM table 
WHERE something IN ('this', 'that', 'other') 
AND thingamajig IN ('one', 'two')
```

Additionally, using the `IN` operator [performs much faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782915/mysql-or-vs-in-performance) than using `OR`.

Comment: I would like to use IN but -- and I should have made this clear in my original post -- I need to be able to distinguish between ('this' OR 'that' OR 'other') and ('this' AND 'that' AND 'other'). This is because we get the this/that/other data from a search form. If someone checks off 5 things and selects "match any" - we need to run the query with OR in place. If they select "match all" we need to run with AND in place.

Answer (score 4):

`AND` [takes precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html) over `OR` in SQL. This means your first query equates to this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM table 
WHERE something = 'this' 
    OR something = 'that' 
    OR (something = 'other' AND thingamajig = 'one') 
    OR thingamajig = 'two'
```

which is obviously not the same result as your second query, and is likely not your intended behavior.

In this case you could use `IN`, which would happen to fix your issue, but in general, it is good to understand operator precedence so that you know the result of various AND and OR combinations.

So, to be clear, you could rewrite your first query as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *     
FROM table     
WHERE (something = 'this'         
        OR something = 'that'         
        OR something = 'other')         
    AND (thingamajig = 'one'         
        OR thingamajig = 'two')
```

Whether you then convert that to use `IN` statements will have no effect on output, and lilely no effect on performance either, so is more of a matter of coding style and elegance than anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Use `IN` instead of `=`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM table 
WHERE something IN ('this', 'that', 'other') AND 
      thingamajig IN ('one', 'two')
```

`IN` is similar to `OR` so performance is the same. Your second query produces syntax error. Because only `comma` is allowed in `IN` clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM table 
WHERE something = ('this' OR 'that' OR 'other') 
    AND thingamajig = ('one' OR 'two')
```

Comment: Can you please expand on this? Is `IN` faster? Does it give different results? Are there differences between the two posted pieces of code?

Comment: nico - Your second piece of code will not work because you need to use an IN clause instead of =.  Your first piece of code won't work correctly because you are not using parenthesis around your "OR" conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use UNIONs like this:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT * 
FROM 
   table 
WHERE 
    something = ('this', 'that', 'other') 
UNION
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
   table 
WHERE 
   thingamajig IN ('one', 'two')
```

Your query can be more 'identified' using flag vars for each SELECT...

```
SELECT
  'FOO_CASE_1' as case
FROM
  DUAL
UNION
SELECT
  'FOO_CASE_2' as case
FROM
  DUAL
ORDER BY
  1
```

This way leaving your debug more easy ;)