# MYSQL query WHERE IN vs OR

Tags: mysql, sql, where-in

I have developed a system using an OR query:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA 
JOIN tableB ON (idA = idB)
WHERE idA = 1 OR 
      idA = 2 OR 
      idA = 3 OR 
      idA = 4 OR 
      idA = 5 ...... OR 
      idA=100
```

Compare with query IN:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA JOIN tableB ON (idA = idB)
WHERE idA IN (1,2,3,4,5,......,100)
```

What is the best query in a MYSQL database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL OR vs IN performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782915/mysql-or-vs-in-performance)

Comment: For things like this, unless you know that this query is a bottleneck in your application, it's not worth the messy logic of multiple `OR` clauses. (Even if it were a little faster.)

Comment: IN() is a syntax shortcut which is (*in syntax terms*) exactly the same as a series of ORs i.e. `id IN(1,2)` is equal to `( id=1 OR id=2 )`.  At small scale you will be hard pressed to locate any difference between the two. At very large scale the interpretation time of a long set of ORs will be at a disadvantage.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use IN.

IN will use an index.

OR will (afaik) not use an index.

Also, and this point is not to be sneezed at, the IN version:

- uses less code
- is easier to maintain
- is easier to understand

For those reasons alone I would be prepared suffer a little performance to gain code quality, but you actually gain performance too.

Comment: I know this is years later, but both use of ORs and IN()  can (and do) use indexes. As with so many things generalizations are dangerous. In syntax terms IN() is simply a shortcut for a set of ORs. see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c824e2/1 (3 IN queries, 3 OR queries, all 6 use an index; varchar, date, and integer tested) MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 4):

In a case like this you should run the queries through EXPLAIN to check how it works against YOUR data. For example:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tableA

JOIN tableB ON (idA = idB)

WHERE idA = 1 OR idA = 2 OR idA = 3 OR idA = 4 OR idA = 5 ...... OR idA=100
```

This will provide several stats and show whether it's making use of indexes, sequential scans, etc. From that you'll be able to determine what works best for your case.

In general, however, I would go with IN.

Previous work has identified that IN will almost always be faster: [MYSQL OR vs IN performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782915/mysql-or-vs-in-performance#2481458)

Comment: i get same output using EXPLAIN, i use DESC and get difference value of Showing query time, for OR ( Query took 0.0082 sec ) and  IN  ( Query took 0.0074 sec )

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tableA

JOIN tableB ON (idA = idB)

WHERE idA <= 100
```

Comment: hmm, i think's my query not sequence for idA, but idA is random value,, i just create easy example question :)

Answer (score 0):

Never use Or if you have In as alternative.

It makes your query super slow