# SELECT * WHERE var == [one of many alternatives]

Tags: mysql, sql, database, where-clause

In MySQL, I can specify an alternative match with `OR`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE var = 1 OR var = 2
```

When there are many alternatives, listing them all like this will become cumbersome. Is there a way, where I can give a list, vector or array of values? Sort of like this pseudocode:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE var IN {1, 2, 5, 11, 45}
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE var IN (1, 2, 5, 11, 45)`

Comment: @Ryan Thank you! I can't believe I almost made up the correct way :-)

Comment: For the person voting to close: No, this question was not caused by a typographical error. I made up the "solution" from my understanding of maths, where braces represent a set, and from R code, where "IN" is used to select from a vector. It is an accident that it resembled the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify [`IN`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm) with parenthesis rather than braces.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE var IN (1, 2, 5, 11, 45)
```

Answer (score 1):

**First** `equality/comparison` operator in `MySQL` is `=` only not `==`.

**Yes** you can achieve the same by introducing `IN` clause. But your syntax doesn't comply with `MySQL` standard. It should be:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE your_column IN (1,2,5,11,45)
```

**Note:**

> Use IN.
>
> IN will use an index.
>
> OR will (afaik) not use an index.
>
> Also, and this point is not to be sneezed at, the IN version:
>
> - uses less code
> - is easier to maintain
> - is easier to understand
>
> For those reasons alone I would be prepared suffer a little
>   performance to gain code quality, but you actually gain performance
>   too.

[**OR VS IN**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964286/mysql-query-where-in-vs-or)

Comment: Thank you, @1000111, I skipped the `FROM table` part to make it easier to focus on the parts that I was asking about.

Comment: Also you can take a look at the performance comparison between OR and IN in mysql. Added a reference. @what

Comment: When I see an `OR` in a query that needs to be performant I cry a little. It's true. They're never good news and if you can't stomp them out you've got problems.

Comment: The link you posted is a few years old and simply claims *OR will (afaik) not use an index* and links to an even older post. MySQL is know for having a weak optimizer, but I wouldn't expect that recent versions show any difference for above example (`IN` is just a shortcut for multiple `OR`s). The only way to found out is comparing the actual plans.

Comment: @tadman: You probably cry a lot :-)  `OR`ed WHERE-conditions are perfectly valid (and `IN` simply hides the `OR`), they are definitely bad in joins and might be bad when the optimizer drops index access.

Comment: I would be grateful if you provide any updated version of the above comparison @dnoeth

Comment: @dnoeth Valid and performant are two different things. An unavoidable `OR` can be very punishing on performance. They're usually a sign of a bad schema design or the programmer expecting way too much from the database.

Comment: I'm not a MsSQL guy, but here you are: http://www.tocker.ca/2015/05/25/optimizer-trace-and-explain-formatjson-in-5-7.html, this clearly shows that both are optmized exactly the same.