# Selecting from multiple tables with multiple criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database with three tables: `sample`, `method`, `compound`.

`sample` has the following columns: `id(PK)(int)`, `date(date)`, `compound_id(int)`, `location(varchar)`, `method(int)`, `value(float)`

`method` has the following columns: `id(PK)(int)`, `label(varchar)`

And `compound` has: `id(PK)(int)`, `name(varchar)`, `unit(varchar)`

I am trying to generate a SQL command that only pulls in the unique row for the following criteria:

- Date (`sample.date`)
- Compound Name (`compound.name`)
- Location (`sample.location`)
- Method (`sample.method`)

However, I want to substitute in the labels for some of the `sample` columns instead of the numbers:

- `sample.compound_id` is matched to `compound.id` which has a corresponding `compound.name` and `compound.unit`

The first SQL command I tried to query was:

```
SELECT sample.id, sample.date, compound.name, sample.location, method.label, sample.value, compound.unit
FROM sample, compound, method 
WHERE sample.date = "2011-11-03"
AND compound.name = "Zinc (Dissolved)"
AND sample.location = "13.0"
AND method.id = 1;
```

The output from the above command:

```
id      date        name            location    label       value   unit
1       2011-11-03      Zinc (Dissolved)    13.0        (1) Indivi...   378.261     μg/L
5       2011-11-03      Zinc (Dissolved)    13.0        (1) Indivi...   197.917     μg/L
9       2011-11-03      Zinc (Dissolved)    13.0        (1) Indivi...   92.4051     μg/L
```

But when I look at `sample` and compare `sample.id` to what was returned:

```
id      date    compound_id     location     method     value   
1       2011-11-03  13          13.0         1          378.261
5       2011-11-03  14          13.0         1          197.917
9       2011-11-03  47          13.0         1          92.4051
```

Where `compound.id` 47 corresponds to `compound.id` 47 and `compound.name` "Zinc (Dissolved)".  Compound IDs #13 and #14 are "Copper (Dissolved)" and "Copper (Total)", respectively.

So it seems to be returning rows that meet the criteria for `sample.date` and `sample.location` without regard to `compound.name`.  Given the above criteria, I know that my database should only return one row, but instead I get some `sample.id` rows that have a completely different `sample.compound_id` than the matching `compound.name` that I specified.

I would like to end up with the columns that are `SELECT`ed in the first line to end up in the same order as I wrote them.  This code is for a little database viewer/reporter program I'm writing in Python/Tkinter and relies on the columns being uniform.  The code that I use to initialize the data for the program works as I expect:

```
SELECT sample.id, sample.date, compound.name, sample.location, method.label, sample.value, compound.unit
FROM sample, compound, method 
WHERE sample.compound_id = compound.id
AND sample.method = method.id;
```

Which puts out each unique line in `sample` with the substitutions for `sample.compound_id` to `compound.name` and `sample.method` to `method.label` and adds in the `compound.unit` at the end.

Question #1: How do I need to restructure my query so that it only returns the row that meets that specific criteria?

Question #2: Eventually I'm going to need to specify multiple `sample.locations` at one time.  Is that as simple as adding an `OR` statement for each individual location that I need?

Comment: For first query - the one that is not meeting criteria - missing Join on info like sample.comapund_d = compound.id. Also you might have to check spelling for compound.name values or consider to use compound.name LIKE 'Zinc%'

Comment: Anda Iancu: I'm a SQL-dummy.  I'm not sure how the INNNER JOIN syntax would work with this amount of criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT sample.id, sample.date, compound.name, sample.location, method.label, sample.value, compound.unit
FROM sample 
INNER JOIN compound ON compound.id = sample.compound_id 
INNER JOIN method ON method.id = sample.method
WHERE sample.date = '2011-11-03'
AND compound.name = 'Zinc (Dissolved)'
AND sample.location = "13.0"
AND method.id = 1;
```

Comment: I thought it was going to be an easy fix!  That did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Now that I have the first question figured out, I figured out my second question:

```
SELECT sample.id, sample.date, compound.name, sample.location, method.label, sample.value, compound.unit
FROM sample 
INNER JOIN compound ON compound.id = sample.compound_id 
INNER JOIN method ON method.id = sample.method
WHERE sample.date = '2011-11-03'  
AND compound.name = 'Zinc (Dissolved)'
AND sample.location IN ("13.0", "22.0")
AND method.id = 1;
```

And just keep adding `OR`s inside the brackets for each other location.

Comment: use IN clause: AND sample.location IN ("13.0", "22.0")

Comment: Anda Iancu: It looks like both methods work.  Is the IN clause considered more appropriate (and probably easier to read) SQL?

Comment: Yes both methods work -is a preference (or easy to read) - if you have like 200 locations let say 200 OR statements; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782915/mysql-or-vs-in-performance