# difference betweene in and = MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MYSQL OR vs IN performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782915/mysql-or-vs-in-performance)

I was wondering whats the difference between:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE cat = 'cat1' OR cat = 'cat2' OR cat = 'cat3'
```

And:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE cat in ('cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3')
```

Is there any difference? As I tried they both give out same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are identical the `IN()` is just a short-hand version using listing out all of the `OR` statements.

Answer (score 1):

`IN()` just makes for a much shorter, and easier to read, syntax especially when you have a lot of `OR` clauses.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more thing that you can do quite easily with `IN` but you can't with `=`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table`
WHERE `column` IN (
    SELECT col_name
    FROM `table2` -- or the same table
    WHERE `some_column` = 5
)
```

So basically you search in a subset of another table, which sometimes comes in handy.

**Real life usage:**

- You have a list of administrable user types (each with its own permissions) in another table, and you want to enforce that the user type actually exists.