# Do using "IN" and "a number of ORs in same SQL query" are Equivalent?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

Consider the following two queries:

**Query 1**

```
Select * from table where field = value1 OR field = value2 ... OR field = valueN
```

**Query 2**

```
Select * from table where field IN (value1, value2 , .... , valueN)
```

Are the two queries has same effect on the DB?
or Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: They are identical. The final word on this has the execution plan

Comment: They are not. The execution plan isn't the end of the story, and the evidence backs that up in [this duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782915/mysql-or-vs-in-performance), which finds some cases where `IN` is significantly faster. That said, the difference is unlikely to ever present a problem in reality.

Answer (score 3):

No difference!!

Finally in Database internal

This query

```
Select * from table where field IN (value1, value2 , .... , valueN)
```

get converted into

```
Select * from table where field = value1 OR field = value2 ... OR field = valueN
```

Comment: Yes, the query optimizer step makes them equivalent.