# Trying to remove an inner SQL select statement

Tags: sql, select

I am making a music player where we have stations. I have a table called histories. It has data on the songs a user likes, dislikes or skipped. We store all the times that a person has liked a song or disliked it. We want to get a current snapshot of all the songs the user has either liked (event_type=1) or disliked (event_type=2) in a given station.

The table has the following rows:

- `id` (PK int autoincrement)
- `station_id` (FK int)
- `song_id` (FK int)
- `event_type` (int, either 1, 2, or 3)

Here is my query:

```
SELECT song_id, event_type, id 
FROM histories 
WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) AS id 
             FROM histories 
             WHERE station_id = 187 
               AND (event_type=1 OR event_type=2) 
             GROUP BY station_id, song_id)  
ORDER BY id;
```

Is there a way to make this query run without the inner select? I am pretty sure this will run a lot faster without it

Comment: If this is MySQL, show us what putting `EXPLAIN` in front of the rest of your query will produce.  Any query that's not pulling from an indexed or key column will slow it down.

Comment: why are you pretty sure? have you examined the query plan and found out what is wrong with it, and is it really about the inner select or something else?

Comment: a simple query seems to be enigh as described `SELECT song_id, event_type, id 
FROM histories
WHERE station_id = 187 
AND (event_type=1 OR event_type=2) 
ORDER BY id;`

Comment: If this is in SQL 2012 or Oracle 11g you can use analytical functions to speed it up. But I see you already have an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `JOIN` instead. Something like this:

```
SELECT h1.song_id, h1.event_type, h1.id 
FROM histories AS h1
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT station_id, song_id, MAX(id) AS MaxId
   FROM histories 
   WHERE station_id = 187 
     AND event_type IN (1, 2) 
   GROUP BY station_id, song_id
)  AS h2  ON h1.station_id = h2.station_id 
         AND h1.song_id    = h2.song_id
         AND h1.id         = h2.maxid
ORDER BY h1.id;
```

Comment: `id` is a PK. No other columns are necessary in the derived table (aka "subquery"). Alternative this is, but faster than the original - not.

Comment: sorry, can you explain why this isn't faster? (because it is much faster from what I'm seeing)

Comment: @jamesatha - I am not sure. But, this might be faster than the original one because of the `INNER JOIN` instead of the `IN` predicate.

Comment: is the `IN` predicate better than the OR's?

Comment: @jamesatha - Yes, the `IN` predicate is faster than multiple `OR`s see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782915/mysql-or-vs-in-performance

Answer (score 3):

@Mahmoud Gamal answer is correct, you probably can get rid of the some conditions that is not needed.

```
SELECT h1.song_id, h1.event_type, h1.id 
FROM histories AS h1
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT MAX(id) AS MaxId
   FROM histories 
   WHERE station_id = 187 
     AND event_type IN (1, 2) 
   GROUP BY song_id
)  AS h2  ON h1.id = h2.maxid
ORDER BY h1.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, this is the answer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT song_id, event_type, id 
FROM histories 
WHERE station_id = 187 
AND (event_type=1 OR event_type=2) 
ORDER BY id
```

But you must be doing the MAX for some reason - why?

Comment: We need the MAX since i want the current snapshot. If a song is liked and later disliked in the station, the latest one (with the highest id value) needs to be the one we return