# PHP MySQL Query ignores AND statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following PHP query that executes a MySQL query without error but is ignoring the city portion of the query at the end?  Is there a way I have to arrange the AND/OR statements?

```
$sql_query = "SELECT ListOfficeMLSID AS list_office_mlsid, MLSNumber AS mls_number, City AS city, ListPrice AS list_price FROM my_table WHERE ListOfficeMLSID =\"office6\" OR ListOfficeMLSID =\"office7\" OR ListOfficeMLSID =\"office2\" AND ListPrice >= 1500000 AND city = \"Bonita Springs\" OR city = \"Estero\"";
```

Comment: It's because AND statements have a priority than OR statements - `1 AND 2 OR 3` is true if 3 is true, or if 1 and 2 are both true. Use brackets to force things to be validated in the order you want - `1 AND (2 OR 3)` is true if 1 is true and if at least one of 2 and 3 is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql_query = "SELECT ListOfficeMLSID AS list_office_mlsid, MLSNumber AS mls_number, City AS city, ListPrice AS list_price FROM my_table WHERE ListOfficeMLSID IN('office6','office7','office2') AND ListPrice >= 1500000 AND city IN('Bonita Springs', 'Estero')";
```

Comment: Is use of IN better performance-wise or more for keeping the query easier to maintain?

Comment: I did it like that because it'll be easy to mantain, but according to this  [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782915/mysql-or-vs-in-performance): it's also performance-wise

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql_query = "SELECT ListOfficeMLSID AS list_office_mlsid, MLSNumber AS mls_number, City AS city, ListPrice AS list_price FROM my_table WHERE (ListOfficeMLSID =\"office6\" OR ListOfficeMLSID =\"office7\" OR ListOfficeMLSID =\"office2\") AND ListPrice >= 1500000 AND (city = \"Bonita Springs\" OR city = \"Estero\")";
```

As I understand you want to get record that has ListOfficeMLSID in (office2, office6 or office6) AND ListPrice >= 1500000 AND city in(Bonita Springs or Estero)?

Your query will return records that suits at least one of your conditions