# CakePHP right way to do this (get value from setting's table)

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a table called `Settings` with fields `key`, `value` and in a view I have to show 5 items from this table using CakePHP, in `Controller`'s action I have put this:

```
$this->set('config', array(
        'key1' => $this->Setting->getValue('key1'),
        'key2' => $this->Setting->getValue('key2'),
        'key3' => $this->Setting->getValue('key3'),
        'key4' => $this->Setting->getValue('key4'),
        'key5' => $this->Setting->getValue('key5')

    ));
```

and in `Setting->getValue();` I have this:

```
function getValue($strKey){
        $value = $this->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'key' => $strKey
             ),
            'fields' => array(
                'Setting.value'
            )
        ));
        return $value['Setting']['value'];
    }
```

there's a more "CakePHP way" to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are retrieving values one by one which is not the right way.

Do it in a single query by making array of values:

```
$inArray = array('val1','val2','val3','val4','val5');

function getValue($inArray){
     $returnData = $this->find('list',array(
                       'conditions' => array('key'=>$inArray),
                       'fields' => array('key', 'value))
             );
     return $returnData;
      }
```

The answer given by @kai contains OR statement which is not optimised way of making such queries, for reference: [MYSQL OR vs IN performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782915/mysql-or-vs-in-performance)

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do it this way:

```
$this->find(
   'list', 
   array(
      'conditions' => array(
          'OR' => array(
                array('key' => 'key1'),
               /*etc*/
           ),
       ),
       'fields' => array('key', 'value)
    )
);
```

You should get an array that looks like this:

```
 array('key1' => 'val1', 'key2' => 'val2', /*etc*/);
```

Comment: Another question, that should be in Model or should I create a Behavior?

Comment: The code that Kai suggested should go in your controller, ie: $config = $this->find(...  , then $this->set(compact('config'));

Comment: I thought that `$this->find..` should go in Model, and Controller calls Model's function.