# Greater than vs in condition mysql performance

Tags: mysql, performance

I have posts table, post's status is a `tinyint`, can be a number between 1-10. I need to select those posts, that have status either of these numbers - 6, 7, 8, 9, 10. So, what solution will be better in terms of performance

```
1) SELECT id, title, status FROM posts WHERE status > 5

2) SELECT id, title, status FROM posts WHERE status IN(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

I did not list using `OR`, as from this answer `IN` is faster

[MYSQL OR vs IN performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782915/mysql-or-vs-in-performance)

Thanks

**UPDATE**

`status` column is indexed

Comment: First you have to add an index on status.

Comment: @majimboo, thanks, forgot to mention it, updated

Answer (score 1):

See this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/346380/3

Select <:

```
Record Count: 2; Execution Time: 27ms
```

Select < explain:

```
ID  SELECT_TYPE TABLE   TYPE    POSSIBLE_KEYS   KEY KEY_LEN REF ROWS    EXTRA
1   SIMPLE  supportContacts range   helper  helper  5   (null)  2   Using where
```

Select IN:

```
Record Count: 2; Execution Time: 1ms
```

Select IN explain:

```
ID  SELECT_TYPE TABLE   TYPE    POSSIBLE_KEYS   KEY KEY_LEN REF ROWS    EXTRA
1   SIMPLE  supportContacts ref helper  helper  5   const   2   Using where
```

As most say TYPE `ref` would be faster than `range`. So I believe the latter will be more faster.

This should be a good read: [Write better SQL queries with Explain](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect the IN-clause to be slightly faster, because it can use the given values as direct keys to the index and thus to the rows.

Using GT will have at least one additional operation to determine all of that keys.

But majimboos approach is generous: Use EXPLAIN to see what will happen in a concrete case.