# SELECT ... WHERE `row` IN (..., ...) with prepared statements?

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

I use `MySQLi` prepared statements. Which is better:

1. `WHERE row=?` and execute as many times as many values
2. `WHERE row IN (?, ?, ?)` bind as many times as many values

**EDIT:** Table has ~20k rows and I may want to look for 1-20k values in that field (all 20k makes no sense, of course).

Comment: Second solution is the best : only one query.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782915/mysql-or-vs-in-performance

Comment: Index the column in question and use `'IN'`

Answer (score 0):

I am using `IN` all the time more readable and more maintainable than the first. Performance based `IN clause` is much better.

[Read more here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4ca39765-6521-4dec-aec1-373b1adf0be7/how-does-the-in-clause-affect-performance?forum=transactsql)

Answer (score 0):

> IN is fine it is optimized. But make sure you use it on an indexed
>   column. It's functionally equivalent to (where : a=1 OR a=2 OR a=3).