# Why does WHERE IN run faster when checking multiple ids?

Tags: mysql

I have a simple `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE ParentId IN (0, 1) OR ParentId IS NULL
ORDER BY SortColumn
LIMIT 0, 2048;
```

Why is it that this query runs ***10x*** slower when I write `WHERE ParentId IN (1)` instead of `(0, 1)`?

The query runs faster whether it finds the second id or not.

**Edit:**

It looks like running the query checking for 1 element and without the `OR ParentId IS NULL` runs just as fast as running the query checking for multiple elements.

`ParentId` is a foreign key to another column and therefore indexed.

Why would this matter so much?

Comment: What did your test look like? How many elements do you have?

Comment: What does the execution plan tell you?

Comment: @Shahar There are over 500,000 elements in the table. 6 columns, 3 foreign keys. And an index on the `varbinary(767) SortColumn`

Comment: @RickS It looks like when it's checking multiple elements it does an Order with Filesort = false. When there is only 1 element, it does a Key Lookup instead of a Full Index Scan, It is very likely however that there will be a lot of rows returned.

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782915/mysql-or-vs-in-performance which shows that direct comparison is not necessarily faster, although the OP questions a single value rather than multiple via OR.