# Exclude 2 rows from select

Tags: mysql

I know I can exclude a row like so:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id <>1
```

But I need to exclude 2 products, I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id <>(1,2)
```

But no luck.

Comment: I've had two good answers, what's better NOT IN or an OR?

Comment: [MYSQL OR vs IN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782915/mysql-or-vs-in-performance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id  not in (1,2)
```

`IN` is definately faster than `OR`. See this [MYSQL OR vs IN performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782915/mysql-or-vs-in-performance)

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT`:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `id` NOT IN (1, 2);
```

Performance wise, `IN` is faster than comparison!