# MySQL Where clause same key twice for two separate values

Tags: mysql

I am generating the following query

```
SELECT * FROM Report WHERE submittedOn >= :minDateFilter 
AND submittedOn <= :maxDateFilter AND non_issue = 1 AND 
non_issue = 0 ORDER BY submitted
```

However, I'm not getting anything returned (it works fine if I omit: `AND non_issue = 1 AND 
    non_issue = 0`, or omit just one of these, but nothing is being returned when both of these clauses are present.

Ideally I'd like to keep the statement how it is, as it's generated on the fly and I'd like to be able to display both types of report from the same query.

I feel like my syntax might be incorrect, but it's not throwing any errors, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

`non_issue` can not have 2 values at same time on a given row. I think you would like to use `OR`:

```
 SELECT * FROM Report WHERE submittedOn >= :minDateFilter 
AND submittedOn <= :maxDateFilter AND (non_issue = 1 OR 
non_issue = 0) ORDER BY submitted
```

Comment: better AND non_issue IN (0,1)

Comment: @AlecTMH why you think IN is better?

Comment: I do not know. Maybe the optimizer handles it the same way?!

Comment: It depends of the dataset however the syntax looks better in that case. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782915/mysql-or-vs-in-performance for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `IN` instead of `non_issue = 1 AND non_issue = 0` condition.

The same entry can't be `non_issue` equal to 0 and 1 same time.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Report 
WHERE submittedOn >= :minDateFilter AND 
      submittedOn <= :maxDateFilter AND 
      non_issue IN (0, 1)
ORDER BY submitted
```