# Is it OK to have lots of IDs in a MySQL query using IN

Tags: mysql, optimization

For example:

```
SELECT UserID, count(*) FROM Messages WHERE UserID IN (3,6,8,11,12,13, ...)
```

I guess if you hit the MySQL max query (packet?) size there's a problem, but in terms of optimization, is there a better way to do it when the are a large number of IDs, perhaps by creating a temporary table, inserting the IDs and doing a join? If so, what is the other method and what is the cutoff point to switch to the other method?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen 70K items in an `IN` list.  But it was beginning to show sluggishness.

I would re-design the flow of things so that your 500K ids landed in a table (possible a temp table).  Then I would do a `JOIN`.

There are various limits buried in the MySQL code, but most of them are so high that users rarely hit them.  You are stressing an area beyond anything I have seen.

I think the code builds an array in memory of the `IN` list, then does a binary search.  This should scale well and be efficient.  But the size of this temp array *may* be pushing the memory allocation to the "swap" point.  Swapping is terribly bad for MySQL.

I'm also pretty sure that it de-dups the numbers as it builds that array.

Yes there is a tunable `VARIABLE` that controls the max length of an SQL statement, but you need only a few MB; the default is perhaps 16MB, so it not croak for 500K.

You have not actually tried it yet?  How about trying it with 1M random values.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MYSQL OR vs IN performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782915/mysql-or-vs-in-performance), IN is the fastest way to do this. It also shows that you can do this with thousands of values in the IN; you have to be more specific about "lots", but I don't think there's a practical limitation.

The 4 ways I know of doing this:

IN - fastest, most readable.

OR - slower, less readable - especially in complex where clauses.

UNION

```
SELECT UserID, count(*) FROM Messages WHERE UserID = 3
UNION
SELECT UserID, count(*) FROM Messages WHERE UserID = 6
UNION 
...
```

Again, harder to read, and probably slower.

Finally, inserting the required IDs into a temporary table. The extra I/O, and creating an index on the temporary table etc. almost certainly means this will be noticably slower than IN.

Comment: By "lots" I mean 20,000 to 500,000 IDs