# MySQL Selecting ID having both given values

Tags: mysql

Hopefully someone can help me out here.

I have a table structure like this

```
product_id  filter_id

374         54
374         55
37          64
375         52
375         55
375         56
375         64
```

I have a list of product_id's that I am using to do a WHERE IN

```
select product_id from product_filter WHERE product_id IN (375,37,251,252,261,262,263,264,269,270,271,272,277) and filter_id = 55 and filter_id = 56
```

I am trying to return all the prodcut ids that match the two filter AND statements.  I run this and get nothing back, I also tried doing an INNER join back on the same table, but again nothing returned.   Any idea how I can do this?

My expected result would be product 375 returned since it matches both "AND" filter_id statements.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ....there is no single row where `filter_id` is both 55 **and** 56, so what do you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this.

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID FROM PRODUCT_FILTER
WHERE PRODUCT_ID IN (375,37,251,252,261,262,263,264,269,270,271,272,277)
      AND FILTER_ID IN (55,56) 
GROUP  BY PRODUCT_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT FILTER_ID) = 2;
```

[**CHECK DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b572a4c5b0cacc9a6ef45a46181959c8)

You can `group by` the `product_id` and check the count of `filter_id`. This will ensure that product ID matches both values.

Comment: Thank you!  This seems to work.   Curious what is = 2 for ?

Comment: `2` means we are checking for filter_id that matches 2 values _(55 & 56) in your case_ . If you want to check for 3 values say 55,56 & 57, then you have check for `COUNT(DISTINCT FILTER_ID) = 3` @limit

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have a condition `where filter_id = 55 and filter_id = 56` because it's impossible for a single row to have a filter_id of 55 AND a filter_id of 56.

One option here:

```
select product_id from product_filter WHERE product_id IN (375,37,251,252,261,262,263,264,269,270,271,272,277) AND filter_id IN (55, 56)
```

Comment: Good question and maybe bad wording on my part! I find this to be the best option of the two immediate options I thought of, which would be using OR on filter_id vs using IN on filter_id. The performance of IN is usually considered to be better than the performance of OR (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782915/mysql-or-vs-in-performance). But honesty, I just meant that of all the possible ways to get the results the OP wants, the option I suggested is simple, easy to read and given the lack of context around indexes or table size, should be efficient :)

Comment: Yes, my question was in fact about the wording :)

Answer (score 1):

Your options for the 2nd Filter `filter_id`  must be group by `() and each option added with`or`:

```
select product_id from product_filter WHERE product_id IN (375,37,251,252,261,262,263,264,269,270,271,272,277) and (filter_id = 55 OR filter_id = 56)
```

Or you also use the `IN` function:

```
select product_id from product_filter WHERE product_id IN (375,37,251,252,261,262,263,264,269,270,271,272,277) and filter_id in (55, 56)
```

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah mySQL is my weak point.  Using IN works, but still doesn't that match either 55 or 56?  I need a specific match on if that product ID matches both values.

Comment: It matches both values, see @ArunPalanisamy answer.

Answer (score 0):

your code was wrong because it's impossible to have filter id both 55 and 56

try this:

```
select product_Id from product_filter
where product_id IN (375,37,251,252,261,262,263,264,269,270,271,272,277)
and filter_id in (55, 56)
```